# input type = time how to set 5 minute intervals and close menu when time SELECTED or button to close EDIT

Tags: javascript, html

so I have

```html
<input type = "time" name = "mytime" id = "mytime">
```

the issue is that when the user select a time the menu remains open. is there a way to close the menu after they select a time on it?

Basically when the user click an hour/minute it should close. Or is there a way to add a button

the user see every minute from 0-59

I want the minute to be in interval of 5 so 0,5,10, etc is that possible?

Comment: you can specify "step=300" but it affects only keyboard and may be not supported by all browsers. You need a custom control

Comment: is there a way to do it visually. I'm aware of the step function. But visually they could still pick a time slot like 53min

Comment: do you use any UI library? For example ngx-material-timepicker supports what you want: https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can do `<input type="time" step="300">` where 300 is 5 minutes in seconds.

For more information, see the [MDN Doc for time input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#step)

Comment: yes but the issue is that they still see time that are not 5 minute interval. I do not want the user to see the time that is not a 5 minute interval

Comment: @dragonn did you find any solution for this?

Comment: any solutions found for this ? @Dylan